# Python Merge 2 or more Dicts using a value to handle duplicate keys

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, key

I am merging dictionaries that have some duplicate keys.  The values will be different and I want to ignore the lower value record.

```
dict1 = {1 :["in",1], 2 :["out",1], 3 :["in",1]}
dict2 = {1 :["out",2], 2 :["out",1]}
```

If the keys are equal I want the `key[0][1`] with the greatest value to be in the new dict.
The output of merging these 2 dicts should be:

```
dict3 = {1 :["out",2], 2 :["out",1], 3 :["in",1]}
```

The only way I know to solve this is to run a loop with a condition to determine which one to add  into the merged dict.  Is there a more pythonic way of doing it?

The duplicate keys will be very few and far between, less than 1% if that will make any difference to the end solution.

Comment: If your dictionary values were stored as `[1, "in"]` instead of `["in",1]` (assuming you only have 2 values, or multiple values in order of importance) this would be as simple as `Counter(dict1) | Counter(dict2)` a.k.a the union of multisets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict1 = {1 :["in",1], 2 :["out",1], 3 :["in",1]}

dict2 = {1 :["out",2], 2 :["out",1]}
vals = []
# get items from dict1 and common keys with largest values
for k, v in dict1.iteritems():
    if k in dict2:
        if dict2[k][1] > v[1]:
            vals.append((k, dict2[k]))
        else:
            vals.append((k,v))
    else:
        vals.append((k,v))
new_d = {}
# add all dict2 to a new dict
new_d.update(dict2) 

# add dict1 items and overwrite common keys with larger value
for k,v in vals:
    new_d[k] = v
print(new_d)
{1: ['out', 2], 2: ['out', 1], 3: ['in', 1]}
```

You could also copy and delete:

```
cp_d1 = dict1.copy()
cp_d2 = dict2.copy()

for k, v in dict1.iteritems():
    if k in dict2:
        if dict2[k][1] > v[1]:
            del cp_d1[k]
        else:
            del cp_d2[k]
cp_d1.update(cp_d2)

print(cp_d1)
{1: ['out', 2], 2: ['out', 1], 3: ['in', 1]}
```

Some timings shows copy is  the most efficient and using  `groupby` is the least efficient:

```
In [9]: %%timeit
   ...: vals = []
   ...: cp_d1 = dict1.copy()
   ...: cp_d2 = dict2.copy()
   ...: for k, v in dict1.iteritems():
   ...:     if k in dict2:
   ...:         if dict2[k][1] > v[1]:
   ...:             del cp_d1[k]
   ...:         else:
   ...:             del cp_d2[k]
   ...: cp_d1.update(cp_d2)
   ...: 

1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 µs per loop
In [20]: %%timeit


 ....: vals = []
   ....: for k, v in dict1.iteritems():
   ....:     if k in dict2:
   ....:         if dict2[k][1] > v[1]:
   ....:             vals.append((k, dict2[k]))
   ....:         else:
   ....:             vals.append((k,v))
   ....:     else:
   ....:         vals.append((k,v))
   ....: new_d = {}
   ....: new_d.update(dict2)
   ....: for k,v in vals:
   ....:     new_d[k] = v
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.11 µs per loop


In [10]: %%timeit                 
 {k: max(dict1.get(k), dict2.get(k), key=lambda x: x[1] if x else None)
  for k in dict1.viewkeys() | dict2.viewkeys()}
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.71 µs per loop

In [22]: %%timeit
   ....: l=dict2.items() +dict1.items() # if you are in python 3 use : list(dict1.items()) + list(dict2.items())
   ....: g=[list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(l),lambda x : x[0])]
   ....: dict([max(t,key=lambda x: x[1][1]) for t in g])
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.1 µs per loop


In [61]: %%timeit
   ....: conflictKeys = set(dict1) & set(dict2)  
   ....: solvedConflicts = { key: dict1[key] 
   ....:                       if dict1[key][1] > dict2[key][1] 
   ....:                       else dict2[key] 
   ....:                  for key in conflictKeys } 
   ....: result = dict1.copy()                     
   ....: result.update(dict2)                       
   ....: result.update(solvedConflicts)  
   ....: 

100000 loops, best of 3: 2.34 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

A single dictionary comprehension can do this

```
from operator import itemgetter
{k: max(dict1.get(k, (None, float('-Inf'))), dict2.get(k, (None,float('-Inf'))),
key=itemgetter(1)) for k in dict1.viewkeys() | dict2.viewkeys()}
```

Comment: I came up with a hackier version `{k: max(dict1.get(k, []), dict2.get(k, []), key=lambda v: v[::-1]) for k in set(dict1).union(dict2)}` but i prefer this.

Comment: I'm not sure I can get this to work. I'm getting invalid syntax at `for`

Comment: @fairywings78, what version of Python are you running?

Comment: This depends on `None` comparing less than any other value, which won't work in 3.x and is not the greatest style anyway.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, fair enough. Fixed

Comment: @1_CR, excuse my skill level.  After importing itemgetter it runs but  where is the merged dict stored?  Do I still need to put it together?

Comment: @fairywings78, if your merged dict is named `dict3`, just do this to get it `dict3 = {k: max(dict1.get(k, (None, float('-Inf'))), dict2.get(k, (None,float('-Inf'))),
key=itemgetter(1)) for k in dict1.viewkeys() | dict2.viewkeys()}`

Answer (score 3):

A pythonic solution should rely heavily on the python standard library and the available syntactic constructs. Not only to simplify the code, but also to gain performance.

In your case you can benefit on the fact that only 1% of the keys occur in both dictionaries:

```
 conflictKeys = set(dict1) & set(dict2)      # get all keys, that are in both dictionaries
 solvedConflicts = { key: dict1[key] 
                          if dict1[key][1] > dict2[key][1] 
                          else dict2[key] 
                     for key in conflictKeys }  # dictionary with conflict keys only and their wanted value

 result = dict1.copy()                       # add values unique to dict1 to result
 result.update(dict2)                        # add values unique to dict2 to result
 result.update(solvedConflicts)              # add values occuring in both dicts to result
```

This solution will try to avoid to run the "slow" python interpreter for every key of the two dictionaries, but will use fast python library routines (which are written in C). That is:

- `dict.update()` to merge both dictionaries
- `set.intersection()`(synonym for set1 & set2) to get all conflicts

Only for solving the conflicting keys you need the python interpreter to loop through all entries. But even here you can profit of the pythonic construct ["list comprehenion"](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in  terms of performance (Compared to an imperative for loop). This is due to the fact, that the memory for solvedConflicts could be allocated at once without any reallocations. A imperative for loop would need to increase the resulting solvedConflicts element by element instead and this need a lot of memory reallocations.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using sets can also be helpful, if the intersection of elements is lower as mentioned

```
def out_dict(dict1, dict2):
    dict3 = {}
    s1 = set(dict1)
    s2 = set(dict2)
    for i in s1-s2:
        dict3[i] = dict1[i]
    for i in s2-s1:
        dict3[i] = dict2[i]
    for i in s1.intersection(s2):
        dict3[i] = dict1[i] if dict1[i] >= dict2[i] else dict2[i]
    return dict3
```

Set difference makes sure to take out the difference elements in the list and the intersection is for the common keys between the dictionaries.

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines may be faster for my situation since very few will be duplicates.  Will have a closer look after work today.

Comment: given that `dict.viewkeys()` (in 2.7) and `dict.keys()` (in 3.x) are already set-like objects, there is no need to create new sets

Comment: Can we use intersection with viewkeys method?

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator

def choose_value(key, x, y):
    """Choose a value from either `x` or `y` per the problem requirements."""
    if key not in x:
        return y[key]
    if key not in y:
        return x[key]
    # "The maximum of x[key] and y[key], ordered by their [1] element"
    return max((x[key], y[key]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

def merge(x, y):
    # "a dict mapping keys to the chosen value, using the union of the keys
    # from x and y as the result keys"
    return {
        key: choose_value(key, x, y)
        for key in x.keys() | y.keys()
    }
```